# .htaccess strip everything after ?tag

Tags: redirect

I need to remove everything after and including "?tag". The problem I've is that the product, for example "1-4-inch-cmos-720p-wi-fi-video-door-phone" always is different.

Is URL: https://www.netmart.club/1-4-inch-cmos-720p-wi-fi-video-door-phone?tag=Video%20Door%20Phone

Should be rewritten to: https://www.netmart.club/1-4-inch-cmos-720p-wi-fi-video-door-phone

I'm playing for days with this issue, and I hope you got an solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Hermann

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^))tag
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]